# Sass Design Pattern: Conditional Selector List

Tags: css, sass

I often need to build CSS group selectors using conditionals and am looking for a more efficient coding pattern.

For example, I have a config file that toggles whether the `audio`, `canvas`, and `video` elements should be reset/normalized:

```
$normalize-html5-audio-element: false;
$normalize-html5-canvas-element: true;
$normalize-html5-video-element: true;
```

Then in my `_normalize.scss` partial, I want to have a group selector that includes only the elements set to true.

I solved it in a very simple way, but it's clunky and not easily scalable. Can anyone suggest a better way?

```
%normalize-html5-media {
    display: inline-block;
    @if $legacy-support-for-ie6 or $legacy-support-for-ie7 {
        *display: inline;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
}

$html5-media-selector: null;

@if $normalize-html5-audio-element {
    $html5-media-selector: audio;
}
@if $normalize-html5-canvas-element {
    @if $html5-media-selector {
        $html5-media-selector: #{$html5-media-selector}, canvas;
    } @else {
        $html5-media-selector: canvas;
    }
}
@if $normalize-html5-video-element {
    @if $html5-media-selector {
        $html5-media-selector: #{$html5-media-selector}, video;
    } @else {
        $html5-media-selector: video;
    }
}

#{$html5-media-selector} {
    @extend %normalize-html5-media;
}
```

Comment: Is there a legitimate reason to split up the selector that way?  `video, canvas` is barely saving anything over `video, canvas, audio`.

Comment: Figured someone would ask that - this is the simplest example I could post; I have other instances where the payoff/savings are greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using your first 3 variables for a second purpose (such generating selectors elsewhere), this would be simpler:

```
$html5-media-selector: ();

@if $normalize-html5-audio-element {
    $html5-media-selector: append($html5-media-selector, audio, comma);
}
@if $normalize-html5-canvas-element {
    $html5-media-selector: append($html5-media-selector, canvas, comma);
}
@if $normalize-html5-video-element {
    $html5-media-selector: append($html5-media-selector, video, comma);
}

#{$html5-media-selector} {
    @extend %normalize-html5-media;
}
```

Or:

```
@if $normalize-html5-audio-element {
    audio {
        @extend %normalize-html5-media;
        // other extends/styles
    }
}
@if $normalize-html5-canvas-element {
    canvas {
        @extend %normalize-html5-media;
        // other extends/styles
    }

@if $normalize-html5-video-element {
    video {
        @extend %normalize-html5-media;
        // other extends/styles
    }
}
```

Otherwise:

```
$html5-media-selector: audio, video !default;

#{$html5-media-selector} {
    @extend %normalize-html5-media;
}
```

Note that if your selector is going to be more complex than just referencing elements, you'll need to quote and `unquote()` before you append:

```
$form-input-text: unquote('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"]');
```

Comment: Thanks cimmanon - I wasn't aware of the append() feature and expect this will work nicely.